# How to compare strings and return position in a linked node?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to write a method that returns the position of a given object in a linked list.

The method signature should be `public int getPosition(T anObject)`.

I am having trouble figuring out this method. Here is what I have so far:

```
public int getPosition(T anObject) {
    int position = 0;
    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(anObject.equals(currentNode.data)) {
            position = i + 1;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

My output position isn't changing. It stays at zero.

Here is my driver program.

```
public class Homework3Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String[] names = {"Abby", "Bobby", "Carla", "Doug"};
      LList<String> nameList = new LList(names, 4);

      String[] newNames = {"Edgar", "Frank"};
      nameList.addAll(newNames);

      System.out.println("Output should be 3: " + nameList.getPosition("Carla") + "\n");
      System.out.println("Output should be 0 or a negative number: " + nameList.getPosition("George") + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your loop, when it finds a matching node, store the current position and `break` out of the loop rather than trying to continue the search...mind you you, can figure out how you get a matching element to begin within...

Comment: @nem [homework questions are allowed on stack overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Ive been working on this for a while and I can't seem to figure out how to get the position returned. Would using a while loop be better but i'm confused on how to make the position increment when the objects are equal.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution might be to iterate through the list, counting position and comparing node-by-node until you reach your node.

```
public int getPosition(T anObject)  {
    int position = 0;
    Node currentNode = firstNode;

    while(currentNode != null) {
        if(anObject.equals(currentNode.data)) {
            break; // we found our node so we can stop searching
        }
        position++;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    // we iterated through the whole list and didn't find the node
    if(currentNode == null) {
        return -1; // or some other error value
    }

    return position;
}
```

Comment: which of these two ways would be more efficient? I don't really understand that part of programming yet. I'm assuming making it more efficient is iterating through the list less times so the computer doesn't have to work as hard?

Comment: @user3242607 This is more efficient as it will exit the loop as soon as a match is made, the other example will continue to loop until it reaches the end of the list, regardless of where the match is made, meaning it will ALWAYS search the entire list.  This will return the first match, the other will return the last match...

Comment: @user3242607 MadProgrammer's answer explains it all :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer just saw your answer haha, yup :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a moment to think about your logic...

Basically, you want to loop while `currentNode` is not `null` AND `anObject` is not equal to `currentNode.data`.  When either of of those conditions become `true`, you want to exit the loop

For example...

```
int position = 0;
Node currentNode = firstNode;    
while (currentNode != null && !anObject.equals(currentNode.data)) {
    position++;
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
}

return currentNode == null ? -1 : position;
```

Note, there are other ways to achieve it this, but this was just what popped into my head...

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This solution will continue to look for items until it gets to the end of the list. This means that it will return the position of the **last** matching item in the list and may be better suited for a `getLastPosition()` method.*

You have to update the `currentNode` every iteration of the loop, not only if it matches:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(anObject.equals(currentNode.data))
    {
        position = i + 1;
        //currentNode = currentNode.next;  // NOT HERE
    }
    currentNode = currentNode.next; // HERE
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer how so?

Comment: You need to add break when you find the right value and increment the counter outside of the loop.

Comment: You don't need a break, this will find the last index of the item instead of the first. He doesn't specify it needs to find the first value. Why do you need to increment the counter outside the loop?

Comment: Yeah, I can see where your logic is running, it will work, but it's inefficient...as you will ALWAYS search the entire list, even if the first element matches.  What happens if you have more elements that match....

Comment: @MadProgrammer than it returns the last matching index. Maybe it would be better suited for a `getLastPosition()` method, but he never specifies the behavior with multiple matching values

Comment: @clcto Then I would highlight that to the OP, the poor poster is already confused enough ;)